# Why are the voltages the way they are in this transistor circuit?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, nmos, pmos, pn-junction

This question is about what my book calls "transmission voltage" when an nmos is conncted to the power source, or a pmos is connected to ground. It has a hypothetical diagram ass shown:

[image]

It also has a text to describe this, I have underscored in red the most relevant part:

[image]

It is the details about this I am wondering about:

1. In the first case when we have 0 volts in A and 0 volts in B. Do we then get 1 volts because there is 0,5 volts over each of the p-types? If so, what is the details that gives us this voltage over the p types?
2. Do we in the other cases get 0,7 volts, because we are connected to the power supply, but we lose 0,5 volts over the n type? Again, what is the details that causes a (negative) voltage over the n types in this case?

Comment: These hypothetical gates may not have enough gate voltage to conduct, so there is some conduction voltage for ON and OFF . This is hypothetical (not real). But it is not an OR gate but rather a NAND gate.

Comment: right ... the Nmos Pmos are reversed

Comment: here's a rough simulation using Vt=0.7  gates https://tinyurl.com/y48r7c55  OR gates with poor margins

Comment: The problem is Pch gates don't work well on the low side  as well as the NAND gate with Pch on the high side https://tinyurl.com/y26yvjct

Comment: Are you familiar with *analog* MOS amplifiers? If so, what can you conclude about your FETs when they're configured in a common *drain* topology?

Comment: @nanofarad No, unfortunately I am not familiar with that. I am familier with mosfets, but not with amplifiers.

Comment: I've never heard this called a transmission voltage before, where did you read this?

Comment: @Hearth The book "introduction to computing systems, from bits & gates to C/C++ & beyond", third edition, section 3.2.3.

Comment: @Hearth What is it called then?

Comment: @user394334 I don't know that I've heard it called anything.

Answer (score 2):

Basically it comes down to how logic-level FETs need to be biased to be fully on or off.

FETs have a characteristic gate-source *threshold voltage*, Vgs, that must be met before they turn on.

- N type: the gate voltage must be *above* the source +Vgs threshold
- P type: the gate voltage must be *below* the source -Vgs threshold

Let's have a look in a sim with what they drew, and compare it to the behavior when N and P are in their 'right' places:

[image]

Simulate it here: [NAND Gate Sim](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCsICMZICYaoOyYMxgByoBsAnCZiHBAlQFABmIWqT%20%20IOORr7iUFKMKgYcuTAiAAsMcewgoB0YQHcm02Woio24WquY9NhsLQAyTVJI2JM3dHPAh6AQwA2AZwCmSNLoCyUjKocNySRFbB3PKQmLBx8TCItABKotyIklac3CRRjuqIvvJQcLQA5mkcROzZgcUmjAY4cCy1zSx8ClBCIpZaEngREtGKPaq1GVlgVpO649NImRwLiCQsJuNis9IQsxt1i1Y7SGtzlfaViETyepfXFjP3%206iWSPcvESFnH0xfP%203fV4ApotXTmH6RJC2X55CAuDzeQrrW6DB7LT5RFELSG1SH7XFfXGYZGbOxfY5424U14Ur74sSotpiEwABwOkOOXF4jhMFU51QOxxuFUw%20CyAtFRxkNzZkphIDlXKQPNuxIgqLVlX2cp%20OrpqvQ8r1mNUmshZuJZ2q7HNhspqmtaMdlPM1xtXxCWjpjnhXh8JJAbo4oKIhNB%20yDkKDAIjEiuEEj%20tNhvjgbjTwN-XYmtT2rFhwV%20dWAZzSzle1ujtmVdO2pTSyrSwagb%20OjNOhG3WEjDNEh1cf4XfKCsNSs1Qt0qVLVk1uR5gX985QpQCxpAYvdsJiZjTNokno0uycbj9SKtrfYRFe2jklevEivEQ7IlD3ABmpjg8E3cD98vOguToYiHAAPQx7hwchAxwKQ1BAAAxABLMpIAAHXcHAYgACmcABKWgwLgPBKCsEh1DgCgIisAA5dDnAAOwAE3QgAFdCAGMAHsACduM8diABdXAAT3QgAjRDnC8Zj3Cw6iAEFqIAEXQgBxZwBM8fD9HUC4IWGO8hkvCQLhMIA)

The example they show never gives the FETs a fighting change to do their jobs, because the Vgs biasing isn't right. Basically, the Fig. 3.7(a) circuit makes the FETs behave as *followers*, which means that the source will always be no closer than one Vgs threshold to the gate voltage.

That is, assuming Vgs threshold of 0.7V (as in the sim):

- N-FET with source at +1.2, with Gate at +1.2, Drain will never be higher than 0.7V (1.2V - 0.7V);
- P-PET with source at 0V, with gate at 0V, Drain will never be lower than 0.7V (0V - (-0.7V))

The sim doesn't show exactly those values. Why? The influence of the two low-side FETs in series, and the exact FET model the sim used.

The point is, the FET needs to have Vgs biased to a useful value to get the result you desire. The second diagram swaps the P and N FETs and *voila!* gives a functioning NAND gate.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have some follow up questions.1.Do you mean that 1,2V-0,7 V=0,5 V, not 0,7 V?(the third bullet point).2.It seems in the simulation that we get the opposite values than in the drawing, that is when we have to L, we have 0,7V, but in the other cases we are closer to 1V, it should be opposite?3. COuld you please explain in all 4 cases why the output is the way it is with the input on A and B as it is.4.Does follower just mean that the threshold voltage is not enough so that means that the souce voltage will be the gate voltage minus the threshold voltage?

Comment: The changes in the voltage is due to the series pair being biased near Vgs, in ‘transmission gate’ threshold. That’s what the text is trying to explain. Try changing the Vgs threshold in the sim and see how it influences the output value. Look at what the biases are doing vs. Vgs, and especially, how that series pair interacts.

Comment: At the same time, the ‘transmission gate’ business is a bit confusing. The near-Vgs biasing mode is used for making a voltage follower or for translating voltage. It’s not useful for making a gate like this, which relies on using saturated mode (that is, Vgs well above threshold.)

Comment: But why does the simulation show opposite values as opposed to what is in the table in my first post? It shows 0,7 when A and B is 0 and higher in the other cases, that is opposite of what is in the table.

Comment: The table is a hot mess that doesn’t match anything. The actual result will vary based upon the FET model in use. Further, the table doesn’t account for the two FETs in series, each with its own bias state. That’s where the simulation comes in, so you can actually see the biasing states.

Comment: Thank you, I have one more question(if you have time). What is it that decides the voltage drop over the p-transistors in the simulation you linked to. When we have LL, all the voltage drop is over the lowest transistor, when we have HL the voltage drop is equal, but when we have LH again all the voltage drop is over the lower transistor?

Comment: The drain-source voltage determines the FET on resistance. As the Vgs gets closer to threshold, the resistance drops. The effect of wiring the P transistors to GND makes a negative feedback effect: as the source is pulled up higher by the leakage of the upper pair, this reduces Rds(on) in the lower pair, to the point where a balance point is achieved between current and Vgs. Try modeling a GND-tied P-FET with a resistor load to +1.2V (you can edit the sim) and see this effect.

Comment: The other thing to remember is that the currents are *very* small. There is leakage current even when Vgs is biased off.

Comment: It works as a High Impedance (>1M)  OR gate but Vgs is never biased with the right polarity on every FET.  So it is a logic of which FET is OFF more than the other.  Threshold set to 250 mV  https://tinyurl.com/y6r8mnr3

Comment: Thank you for your help, sorry I could only give the bounty to one person.

Answer (score 1):

To understand why the shown arrangement does not work properly, study a similar problem that arises when single NMOS and PMOS are used as transmission gates. In CMOS you have the choice of a detached body, therefore, in theory, the transistor is a totally symmetrical device. So the terminal of the transistor that behaves as the source and drain depends on the direction your trying to pass current through it. This is the key to understand why the circuit you have shown does not work well with the NMOS on top and PMOS on the bottom.

In the circuit shown, the source of both the PMOS and NMOS will be the output node. Now this should immediately give off some red flags as you want that node to swing from 0 to VDD, meaning that the VGS of both transistors will change considerably when the output changes! What this means is, before the output changes fully from one end of the rail to the other, the transistor will switch off before that happens fully, leaving the output at some intermediate voltage.

Consider what happens with both inputs are HIGH. The gate of PMOS is at 1.2V and the source of the PMOS, the output node, must be something less than 1.2V, thus the PMOS is off. Now the NMOS gate is also at 1.2V so it tries to turn on, but as this happens the output rises and hence VGS of the NMOS drops, eventually almost switching it off. Thus the NMOS will only operate until the point the output reaches a value such that VGS = Vgate - Vout = VTH = 0.5V. Hence Vout = 1.2 - 0.5 = 0.7V.

[image]

[image]

Look at the blue trace Reqn. This is the resistance or drive strength of the NMOS driving the output when both inputs are HIGH. Do you see how, because Reqn starts to become huge (in theory infinite) so Vout can only go upto a maximum Vdd-Vth as shown on the x-axis Vout?

Comment: Thank you, but I have one follow up question: It is about this "Now the NMOS gate is also at 1.2V so it tries to turn on, but as this happens the output rises and hence VGS of the NMOS drops, eventually almost switching it off. Thus the NMOS will only operate until the point the output reaches a value such that VGS = Vgate - Vout = VTH = 0.5V. " Why do we have that the output of the nmos rises in this case? Isn't the voltage of the source of the nmos now at zero? And how is the fact that the nmos is connected to ground have anything to do with this?

Comment: Why will the NMOS source be at 0V and who said nmos is connected to ground?  ignore the PMOS as it is OFF and imagine just the NMOS with its gate and drain at 1.2V and source (the output node of this cirucit) connected to ground via some large resistance(representing the off PMOS) and some paracitic capacitance. The source will tell begin to rise slowly upto around Vgate - Vth.. Do you see?

Comment: Just ask your self this question: Can a NMOS with drain = 1.2v and gate = 1.2v drive a load connected to its source to 1.2V before switching off? The answer is no, because the NMOS will switch off once the source(output node) reaches 1.2v - Vth, which is what the author is trying to explain. This is what i suspect he means by maximum "transmission voltage".

Comment: So the drain of the nmos is connected to 1,2 volt aswell? And what happens is that the nmos is open, but it will go current through it which will drop the difference of voltage between the gate and the source and that causes the nmos to be turned off? Does the current drop the voltage beacuse there is innter resistane?

Comment: Yes the drain of the NMOS is the top most pin connected to the power rail on the photo you posted. Yes you almost got it, the current through the NMOS starts to flow through the resistance/capacitance at the output node/source node which means slowly this node voltage starts to rise. But as this rises VGS starts to decrease, eventually turning the NMOS off before the source can reach VDD.

Comment: Thank you, so can we summarize it as: When we connect a nmos to the power source we have a problem opening it completely because we will not get the VGS his enough, and when we connect a pmos to ground it has a problem staying open because we also don't get VGS low enough?

Comment: Yes, the problem, i.e low VGS is the same for both NMOS and PMOS where the source is connected to the output. In this scenario the NMOS has trouble "transmiting" a logic high to the output/source because that reduces its VGS until it turns off. Same for the PMOS but the PMOS has trouble passing a logic low because it too will turn off once the VGS reachs around VTH.

Comment: Thank you, so can we use the knowledge you have shared to explain the table in my first post. For instance when A and B are 0, then the nmos is closed, but the pmos is open. The output is then supposed to be connected to ground, but since the pmos won't be able to open completely we will get 1V(0,5V+0,5V)? This is though a little counterintuitive because the output won't be connected to a positive voltage but still, the the pmos transistors wil contribute to positve voltage?

Comment: Well it is connected, think of the NMOS as being a resistor Roff when its off. Just simulate this circuit and play with it.

Comment: Thank you, just one last question: When the NMOS is off, why will it act as a resistor instead of cutting off tehe electricity completely?

Comment: Because its not a perfect switch. It has some finite ON and OFF resistance ofcourse!

Comment: Thank you for your help.